# Should I use latest Cordova every time new Cordova version comes out?

Tags: cordova

My question is: Should I use latest Cordova every time new Cordova version comes out?
How about platforms and plugins - are they upgraded every time with new Cordova version?

Is there a definition of "latest stable" and "latest rc" of Cordova?

I found some commands to install particular version:
npm install -g cordova@3.5
npm update -g cordova@latest

But they are not explained much, so, I'm confused.

I have not found recommendations how to adopt new Cordova viersions?
Should I rush migrating to new Cordova every time it is released, or it is more safe to stick with some specific Cordova version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's always good to work with the latest version available, but you don't really need to update cordova unless there is a critical bug or you need something from the new features.

Examples:

If you are using an android cordova version lower than 3.5.1, there is a critical security bug and google won't accept new apps using cordova versions lower than 3.5.1 and they can detele your app if you don't update it.

If you want to submit iOS apps (new and updates) after february 1st, you will need cordova 3.5, because from february 1st apple will require apps compiled for 64 bits, and cordova included that on cordova 3.5

Now, most of the code is in the plugins, so in most cases you just update the plugins you use if there is a bug on them that is affecting you.

Comment: so if I have an iOS app that was built using version 3.4.0 and already in the store before Feb 1, I should just upgrade my cordova version from CLI for that project, to submit an upgrade for review?

Comment: You have to update the CLI with `npm update -g cordova` and then update the project with `cordova platform update ios`